# Algorithm spanning two columns error with \prevdepth

Tags: errors, algorithms

I am trying to use the `algorithm` command to display an algorithm that spans two columns in a two column document. However, I am getting an error message with `\prevdepth` that I do not understand. Below is a minimal example that illustrates the problem.  Note that this example uses the [sigplanconf.clf](http://drupal.sigplan.org/sites/default/files/sigplanconf.cls) class file:

```
\documentclass[preprint]{sigplanconf}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\begin{document}

\title{a title } 

\authorinfo{an author}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
  abstract 
\end{abstract}

\section{a section }

\begin{algorithm*}
\begin{verbatim}
a long line of text goes here that will take up too much space and need to span columns
\end{verbatim}
\end{algorithm*}

\end{document}
```

If I run latex with `algorithm` instead of `algorithm*` (note the difference with `*`) I do not get any error messages.  However the algorithm text gets mixed with text in the right hand column.

However, if I use `algorithm*` I get the following error message that I do not understand:

```
! Improper \prevdepth. <recently read> \prevdepth 
                            \subfig@end@float ...-\@Miv \@tempdima \prevdepth 
                                                  \vbox {}\prevdepth \@tempd...

\end@dblfloat ...\expandafter \@gobble \end@float 
                                                  \fi \else \end@float \fi  \end #1->\csname end#1\endcsname 
                                 \@checkend {#1}\expandafter \endgroup \if@e... l.291 \end{algorithm*}
                       ?  ! Emergency stop. <recently read> \prevdepth 
                            \subfig@end@float ...-\@Miv \@tempdima \prevdepth 
                                                  \vbox {}\prevdepth \@tempd...

\end@dblfloat ...\expandafter \@gobble \end@float 
                                                  \fi \else \end@float \fi  \end #1->\csname end#1\endcsname 
                                 \@checkend {#1}\expandafter \endgroup \if@e... l.291 \end{algorithm*}
```

I guess there is some conflict with the combination of `subfigure` `fixltx2e` and `algorithm` because when I was creating an example to illustrate the problem I found that if I removed either `fixltx2e` or `subfigure` the problem disappeared.  So I will check my paper to see if I need both of those packages (I'm helping with editing so I'm not sure if they are needed). But if anyone happens to look at this example and understands what is causing the error I would be interested in understanding the root cause.

Comment: Can you work out a minimal example we can play with?

Comment: As egreg mentioned, we need a minimal example; the following simple test document doesn't produce any errors: `\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm*}
\begin{algorithmic}
\State x
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm*}
test
\end{document}`.

Comment: okay I'll work on getting a minimal example together.

Comment: You  get that error for trying to read `\prevdepth` when you are in horizontal (LR) rather than vertical mode `\hbox{\dimen0=\prevdepth}` being the simplest thing. So it is presumably related to your float layout (subfig?)

Comment: @egreg I added an example that demonstrated the error messages I described. thanks for looking at my question.

Comment: The problem seems to be with the (obsolete) package `subfigure`; you may try with `\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}` in its place, changing the `\subfigure` or `\subtable` commands into `\subfloat`.